# Unable to read beyond the end of the stream

Tags: c#, stream

I did some quick method to write a file from a stream but it's not done yet. I receive this exception and I can't find why:

```
Unable to read beyond the end of the stream
```

Is there anyone who could help me debug it?

```
public static bool WriteFileFromStream(Stream stream, string toFile)
{
    FileStream fileToSave = new FileStream(toFile, FileMode.Create);
    BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(fileToSave);

    using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        int pos = 0;
        int length = (int)stream.Length;

        while (pos < length)
        {
            int readInteger = binaryReader.ReadInt32();

            binaryWriter.Write(readInteger);

            pos += sizeof(int);
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question but this method could be so much simpler like this:

```
public static void WriteFileFromStream(Stream stream, string toFile) 
{
    // dont forget the using for releasing the file handle after the copy
    using (FileStream fileToSave = new FileStream(toFile, FileMode.Create))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(fileToSave);
    }
}
```

Note that i also removed the return value since its pretty much useless since in your code, there is only 1 return statement

Apart from that, you perform a Length check on the stream but many streams dont support checking Length.

As for your problem, you first check if the stream is at its end. If not, you read 4 bytes. Here is the problem. Lets say you have a input stream of 6 bytes. First you check if the stream is at its end. The answer is no since there are 6 bytes left. You read 4 bytes and check again. Ofcourse the answer is still no since there are 2 bytes left. Now you read another 4 bytes but that ofcourse fails since there are only 2 bytes. (readInt32 reads the next 4 bytes).

Comment: Amazing, so much simpler like you said! Thanks a LOT :-)

Answer (score 3):

I presume that the input stream have ints only (Int32). You need to test the `PeekChar()` method,

```
while (binaryReader.PeekChar() != -1)
{
  int readInteger = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
  binaryWriter.Write(readInteger);          
}
```

Comment: note that this is not efficient at all. `PeekChar` will actually save the current Position from the main stream, read an int, and again set position!

Answer (score 1):

You are doing while (pos < length) and length is the actual length of the stream in bytes. So you are effectively counting the bytes in the stream and then trying to read that many number of ints (which is incorrect). You could take length to be stream.Length / 4 since an Int32 is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
int length = (int)binaryReader.BaseStream.Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the stream by the binary reader the position of the stream is at the end, you have to set the position to zero "stream.position=0;"